# Adding a drop down list of states IF the box is empty or less than 1 character

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a drop down list of state codes so a user can select from it if there is an empty box or if there is an error ("N" instead of "NJ"). I want this happen in all cells in column L apart from header.

I have a separate table with the state codes which is located here: Schema_1099 Recipient'!$D$27:$D$76

```
Sub state_list()
    For Each cell In Range("L1:" & "L" & LastRow)
        If Len(cell.Value) >= 1 Then
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='Schema_1099 Recipient'!$D$27:$D$76"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I am able to code the simple dropdown in one cell, but I want it to appear on all cells in the column.

Comment: So what's the problem you're having?

Comment: This code is not working. I want to have the drop down menu on all cells in column L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete and needs a few tweaks.
You will need to add code to determine the lastrow variable, I set it to 10 for testing purposes.    You also needed a EndIf and a With .validation code.
This should work for the active worksheet for rows 2 to 10.

```
Sub state_list()
lastrow = 10
    For Each Cell In Range("L2:L" & lastrow)
        If Len(Cell.Value) >= 1 Then
    With Cell.Validation
            .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='Schema_1099 Recipient'!$D$27:$D$76"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End If
Next
End Sub
```